# cmake add_custom_target with arguments

Tags: linux, bash, cmake

I would like to create a custom target in cmake that calls a bash script with its arguments ie

make foo , where arguments could be multiple as -t -v -p

would call

source foo.sh -t -v -p

I am able to correctly call the script and run it successfully but it is unclear what is the best way to pass to it the arguments verbatim. Any hints?
I am currently using

add_custom_target( foo COMMAND bash -c "source foo.sh" )

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? I don't really see the point in calling bash, because CMake has equivalent functions for many commands, which is cleaner and maintains the platform-independent functionality of CMake.

Comment: I just want to call a bash script as is without changes with its parameters by using make foo <bash script parameters>

Comment: What is in your bash script?

Comment: With autotools we can have for example make install dest=<dir>, what would be the best way to reproduce this with more than one parameters like dest?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with more than one parameter, but you have CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX that you can use on the first cmake call.

Comment: Off hand you can't do what you want because when you use `add_custom_target` it generates a script that gets run by the native tools you are using like Make or Ninja or Visual Studio.  You would have to use some weird escapes based on the system you are using so that it could read environment variables or something when executed on the command line by the build system.

Comment: Also `make` doesn't work that way `make foo -a -b -c` would just build `foo` and all parameters would be passed to `make`.

Comment: Autotools allows for `make DESTDIR=<dir> install` only sets the variable `DESTDIR` variable which gets used by `make` itself when running the `install` target. `install` itself is not a script but a recipe within the Makefile. It's a convenience when you don't want to install to `prefix` as set by the  `configure` script.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, we will add cmake defs to achieve the required